# Data getting entered twice in database whenever web service is fired on button click?

Tags: php, iphone, ios, xcode

I have a xcode project in which i need to enter data on button click and then display it in the TableView.

**Example: Twitter (follow/unfollow).**

1.I click on friend's icon, a list of my friends appear.

2.When I click on any of my friends, their friends list appear in tableview with follow buttons corresponding to them (mutual friends have unfollow buttons).

3.Now, when I click on the follow button and go back to check my friend list, that particular friend has been added twice.

**What I have done so far:**

Checked if the sql db exist somewhere else as well.

Checked if the webservice is being called twice.

Everything's fine. I have iMac and Macbook Pro as well and both of them have same issues.
I have reinstalled Xampp twice but still the same result.

For your reference, following is the php i am using for my Xcode project.

```
<?php
 $id =  $_REQUEST['id'];
 $fid = $_REQUEST['fId'];
 $firstName = $_REQUEST['firstName'];
 $lastName = $_REQUEST['lastName'];

 $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
 if(!$con)
 die("Connection failed"."<br/>");

 $db = mysql_select_db("db",$con);
 if(!$db) die("Database not found!"."<br/>");

 $query = "INSERT INTO $id(firstName,lastName,folks_id)     VALUES('$firstName','$lastName','$fid')";
 print  $query;
 mysql_query($query,$con);
 mysql_close($con);

?>
```

**EDIT: Xcode part for reference**

```
-(IBAction)followButtonClicked:(UIButton *)sender
    {

  NSMutableString *postString = [NSMutableString stringWithString:kFollowURL];
    [postString appendString: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"?%@=%@", kId, [user objectForKey:@"id"] ]];
    [postString appendString: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"&%@=%@", kfId, [fId objectForKey:@"fID"] ]];
    [postString appendString: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"&%@=%@", kfirstName, [firstNameDict objectForKey:@"firstName"] ]];
    [postString appendString: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"&%@=%@", klastName, [lastNameDict objectForKey:@"lastName"] ]];
    [postString appendString: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"&%@=%@", kprofileType, [profileTypeDict objectForKey:@"profileType"] ]];

    [postString setString: [postString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    NSLog(@"post string = %@", postString);

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:postString]];

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    followConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self startImmediately:YES];
    NSLog(@"postconnection: %@", followConnection);

    //Get JSON Response from server

    NSData *dataURL =  [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: [ NSURL URLWithString: postString ]];    
    NSString *serverOutput = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataURL encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding];

    NSLog(@"serverOutput = %@", serverOutput);

 }
```

Comment: Hve you written the database entering part iv viewDidAppear ..please share your ios code for entering data into database.

Comment: The above code is being called twice. Check you didn't `include` the above file twice. Also, I guess you are using a `GET` request to do this (hard to say since you are using `$_REQUEST`)? Firstly, use `POST`, secondly if you must use `GET`, check to see if you have any `<img>` or `<script>` tags with an empty `src=` attribute, or any `<link>` tags with an empty `href=` attribute - any one of those will cause the page to be loaded twice.

Comment: @DaveRandom i am using REQUEST to handle webservice part and from my Xcode ios part, i am using post method.

Comment: @roronoazorro Nope, the database entering part is written in the button click method. I have posted the code in the edit part of the question

Comment: Does this also happen when you visit the page manually in your browser? That way you know for sure where the problem lies, in xCode or PHP.

Comment: Notice your code can be Injected as you're inserting unsafe variables. And mysql_* commands are being Deprecated, so use something else (like PDO or mysqli)

Comment: @TJHeuvel What i did is I manually ran the php in browser by entering the respective REQUEST, the data was getting entered only once

Comment: you are hitting the url 2 times in your button

Comment: @roronoazorro where am i hitting it two times... kindly point that out plz...

Comment: @eric.itzhak could you help me out and tell me what are the best practices to make a server connection so that an unidentified user/hacker couldnt run the script on browser and breach the app...
What all things are to be done on server side...plz help me out...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SOLVED] The thing which did the trick was that i made fid as unique... so now whenever i click on the follow button, it is entered one and not twice.

Thanx to all of you guys for the help and support.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have primary key in your database table.

if it is than how can be possible to insert value against same id.

Comment: make the id or fid as primary key in database

Comment: thnx for the idea... actually fid was primary but it wasnt unique... i amde it unique and it worked....

Comment: check out my answer... i shall accept it within 4 hrs ( according to the stackoverflow permissions)